# Vaadin ComboBox invisible when readonly

Tags: combobox, vaadin, readonly, invisible

Why does a Vaadin ComboBox get invisible when doing setReadOnly(true)?

**Screenshots**

normal 
[image: normal ComboBox - visible]

invisible [image: ComboBox with setReadOnly(true) - invisible]

**The source code**

```
import java.util.List;   
import com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox;

public class PropertyComboBox extends ComboBox
{
    public PropertyComboBox(List<String> properties)
    {
        super();
        for(String property: properties) {this.addItem(property);}
        this.setImmediate(true);
        this.setMultiSelect(false);

        this.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
        this.setInputPrompt("Property");
        this.setReadOnly(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a combo box in which the user can't write anything, check out the [NativeSelect](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html) component.

From the API doc:

> This is a simple drop-down select without, for instance, support for multiselect, new items, lazyloading, and other advanced features. Sometimes "native" select without all the bells-and-whistles of the ComboBox is a better choice.

If you don't need these features, then you should definetely consider using NativeSelect.

Answer (score 1):

All components get "invisible" when you set them to read only. I couldn't find any reason for that and was wondering too.

My suggestion (a bit hacky): disable the components and change their disabled appearence within CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus is right, component become invisible when set to readOnly. In fact setting to read-only add the "v-readonly" css classname and the CSS do the rest.

Regards.